# AspNetCore SignalR, can't read headers and HttpContext

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, httpcontext, asp.net-core-signalr, httpconnection

I'm developing server(console app) on latest .Net 6 platform, using AspNetCore.signalR and in OnConnectedAsync method I want to read headers present in HttpContext, but I can't get HttpContext, I've tried:

```cs
var httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext();
```

But this throws compilation error. Like this method does not exist in this namespace anymore(namespace: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR).

[image]

I also tried following approach:

```cs
var features = Context.Features.Get<HttpConnectionFeature>();
```

But this only gives info about Local/Remote IP Addresses which is useless when using proxy.

So I want to read all context headers, like User-Agent, Remote IP address, X-Forwarded-For and etc.

Any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: Should be var h =  Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers["myHeader"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var httpCtx = Context.GetHttpContext();
        var headers = httpCtx.Request.Headers;
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core package and it didn't contain GetHttpContextExtensions and I could not reach the HttpContext. So I replaced the package with Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72735505/15581227  I think this may help you know more about the package.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the signalR packages on nuget are deprecated, like this one https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core

So just make sure to uninstall any nuget packages of SignalR and instead update your `csproj` file to include the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```